# How to remain on form after pushing "Submit"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

I'm simply looking for a way to remain on my form after I hit the "Submit" button. I want to be able to record multiple data entries with just a few changes between them, but don't want to re-enter **all** of the fields in my form.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

**The** new Item form is for adding *one item* , You can use `Quick Edit`  if you need to enter multiple items, and you can use drag option to copy entries.

[image] 
[image]

Comment: I would also add that using Excel to edit "many" records at once, and then copy-paste them all into the Quick Edit is another good approach. Depending on your exact needs. I find working with the Quick Edit interface directly can be a bit cumbersome.